# Finding Characteristic of a field , order of elements in Subgroup, Centre of Group

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, field-theory

> Let $K$ be a field, $n$ a positive integer and $G$ a finite subgroup of $GL_n(K)$ such that $|G|>1$. Further assume that every $g\in G$ is upper triangular and all the diagonal entries of $g$ are $1$.
>
> (A) Show that $\operatorname{char} K>0$.
>
> (B) Show that the order of $g$ is a power of $\operatorname{char}K $, for every $g\in G$.
>
> (C) Show that the centre of $G$ has at least two elements.

I have been following Joseph Gallian's *Abstract Algebra* and this question was asked in my End Term Exam last week and I couldn't solve any part. I tried it again today but failed to make any progress.

Can you please help me with it.

I understand the definitions and propositions, but I am completely struck on this.

Characteristic of $K$ is the least $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n .1_K =0$, Center of $G = \{x \in G \mid gx =xg \text{ for all } g\in G\}$.

Comment: For $A)$: Try it explicitly for $n=2$ by writing down the uni-triangular matrices. What happens if you multiply two such matrices from $G$?

Comment: For (c): assuming (b), we have that $G$ is a $p$-group, then you can use class equation. By the way, you can prove (b) with a similar idea as our friend posted in the comment above: by looking at small values of $n$.

Comment: Also for (a): look at what would happen if the characteristic of the field was 0: there would be non-torsion elements. Try to look at small values of $n$, like our friend above said.

Comment: You may assume that $K$ is algebraically closed. Do you know that a matrix is diagonalizable if and only if its minimal polynomial has no repeated roots? And this matrix satisfies $X^n-I$. This is a different method. Another one involves taking Jordan normal forms.

Answer (score 4):

For (a) and (b)
really it comes down to writing $g\in G$ as $(I+N)$ where $N$ is strictly upper triangular (and hence nilpotent). There's nothing to do when $g=e$ (i.e. $ N= \mathbf 0$ case), so consider $g \in G-\big\{e\big\}$.

Then $N^r= \mathbf 0$ for some minimal $r\in\big\{2,...,n\big\}$ -- i.e. $N^{r-1}\neq \mathbf 0 = N^r$. And since your group is of finite order, $g^k =e$ for some $k \geq 2$. But this means

$I = (I + N)^k = I + \binom{k}{1}N^1+ \binom{k}{2}N^2+....+ \binom{k}{k-1}N^{k-1} + N^k$
$\implies \mathbf 0 = \binom{k}{1}N^1+ \binom{k}{2}N^2+....+ \binom{k}{k-1}N^{k-1} + N^k$
which is a contradiction if $\text{char }\mathbb F = 0$
Why? Consider multiplying each side by $N^{r-2}$ to get $k\cdot N^{r-1} = \mathbf 0$

Thus $\text{char }\mathbb F = p$, for some prime $p$
This also tells you that $k\%p =0$ and gives you part (b).

For (c)
You can write $\big \vert G\big \vert = p^m \cdot z$.  Where $z\%p \neq 0$. If $z\neq 1$ then applying Cauchy's Theorem gives the existence of an element of an order that isn't a multiple of $p$-- contradicting (b).  Hence $G$ is a $p$ group and must have a center with more than one element.

Comment: I n part C of your proof can you please tell what exactly this term means: $z%p \neq 0$? I think it was a typo

Comment: This also tells you that $ k%p=0$ and gives you part (b). You didn't defined what p is. Can you please do that?

Comment: I added a line to make it explicit that p is the characteristic of your field.  $z$ is stated to be $=\big\vert G\big\vert \cdot p^{-m}$ and not a multiple of $p$.  For avoidance of doubt this means $z \in \mathbb N$. I'm not sure why this seems like a typo.

Comment: Consider the last 3rd line of your answer. What do you mean by the symbol % in z% p $\neq 0$?

Comment: Can you please reply ?

Comment: the % is the *modulo* symbol